# Iam getting 401 error while generating JWT json web token and posting

Tags: python, jwt, actions-on-google, service-accounts, google-client

I am generating JWT json web token with google service account key and trying to post data but i am getting **401** error ,here i am using google client library

```
    def generate_jwt():
    with open("service_account_file.json") as json_file:
        service_account_file_opened= json.load(json_file)

    signer = google.auth.crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_file("service_account_file.json")
    now = int(time.time())
    expires = now + 3600  # One hour in seconds

    payload = {
        'iat': now,
        'exp': expires,
        '**aud**': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation',
        '**iss**': 'notifications@eprint-9ff89.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
        '**sub**': 'notifications@eprint-9ff89.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
        'email': 'notifications@eprint-9ff89.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    }

    jwt = google.auth.jwt.encode(signer, payload)

    return jwt
```

**hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(generate_jwt())}**

```
url = 'https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send'
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(notif), headers=hed)
    print(response)
```

Comment: Only thing 401 tells us is that your Authorization: Bearer header was rejected. Can you give us more details?

Comment: solved thanks yes it was token problem